# Every solution that I've seen for SICP Exercise 3.16 appears to cheat by creating more than three pairs. Where is my misunderstanding?

Tags: list, scheme, sicp, cons

[SICP Exercise 3.16](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-22.html#%25_thm_3.16) gives the reader a broken procedure for counting the numbers of pairs in a list structure:

```
(define (count-pairs x)
  (if (not (pair? x))
      0
      (+ (count-pairs (car x))
         (count-pairs (cdr x))
         1)))
```

It then challenges the reader to create list structures made up of **exactly three pairs** that make this procedure return:

1. 3
2. 4
3. 7
4. Never return.

Tasks #1 and #4 are easy; Just make a normal list of three elements and make a circular list. For tasks #2 and #4, however, every solution that I've seen appears to cheat by creating more than three pairs. For example, [the Scheme Wiki](http://community.schemewiki.org/?sicp-ex-3.16) gives these:

```
 (define x '(foo)) 
 (define y (cons x x)) 
 (define str2 (list y)) 
 (count-pairs str2) ; 4 

 (define x '(foo)) 
 (define y (cons x x)) 
 (define str3 (cons y y)) 
 (count-pairs str3) ; 7

 (define second (cons 'a 'b)) 
 (define third (cons 'a 'b)) 
 (define first (cons second third)) 
 (set-car! third second) 
 (count-pairs first)  ;; => 4 
  
 (define third (cons 'a 'b)) 
 (define second (cons third third)) 
 (define first (cons second second)) 
 (count-pairs first)  ;; => 7
```

I disagree with all of them for the same reason: They appear to be more than three pairs. For example, the final list from the first block of code will be `(cons (cons (cons 'foo nil) (cons 'foo nil)) nil)`. As I've written `cons` more than three times, this isn't made of three pairs. Similarly, the last block is clearly `(cons (cons (cons 'a 'b) (cons 'a 'b)) (cons (cons 'a 'b) (cons 'a 'b)))`, which is far more than three pairs.

Where is my misunderstanding?

Comment: You're missing that `(cons x x)` doesn't duplicate `x`; the `car` and the `cdr` are the same pair.

Comment: @molbdnilo Feel free to turn that in to an answer. That seems to pretty much be what I'm missing.

Comment: This is explained pretty well in the few paragraphs before the exercise. Did you try to solve this by drawing box-and-pointer diagrams, as the exercise says? (It is important for understanding to not solve this with code.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write it as

```
(define x    (cons 'foo '()))
(define y    (cons x x))
(define str2 (cons y '()))
```

How many `cons`es? Three `cons`es! But when we count them, `x` is counted twice, so `(cons x x) ==> (+ 1 1 1) = 3` and then `(cons y '()) => (+ 3 1) = 4`. But still there are exactly three `cons` cells freshly minted there.

Write it as

```
(define x    (cons 'foo '())) 
(define y    (cons x x)) 
(define str3 (cons y y))
```

How many `cons`es? Three `cons`es! But when we count them, `x` and `y` are counted twice, so `(cons x x) ==> (+ 1 1 1) = 3` and then `(cons y y) => (+ 3 3 1) = 7`. But still there are just three `cons` cells freshly minted there.

The two examples exploit *list structure sharing*. Both `car` and `cdr` fields of the cons cell held by `y` point to the same cons cell, held by `x`.

But the program does not know that. It enters the same cons cell -- `x` -- twice, and counts it twice.

It could test for the sameness, with `eq?`. `(eq? (car y) (cdr y))` would return `#t`. But it doesn't make this call.

---

The two list structures, held by `str2` and `str3`, can be represented as -- the first one, first, as --

```
 str2   -->  [ y | [] ]       ; first CONS cell
               |
               |
               [ x | x ]          ; second CONS cell
                 \   /
                  \ /
                   [ FOO | [] ]      ; third CONS cell
```

When you write `(cons (cons (cons 'foo nil) (cons 'foo nil)) nil)` you're writing out the same thing by value, but not *structurally*.

Value equality is checked with `equal?` -- as in, "are the two things printed out the same? Are they indistinguishable when observed by pure means?..." (*pure* here means, not employing `eq?`).

Structure equality is checked with `eq?` -- as in, "are the two things actually the same thing *in computer memory?*..."

"Pure" functional programming concerns itself with abstract "values".

Impure programming concerns itself with concrete structures in computer memory.

---

And the other value is

```
 str3   -->  [ y | y ]
               \   /
                \ /
                 [ x | x ]
                   \   /
                    \ /
                     [ FOO | [] ]
```